# Backbone.js why a model from a collection doesn't have url set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am still relatively new to Backbone. I'm just beginning to get a sense of how it works. I 've been using Rails for a while and it's what is giving me some hint at times of using Backbone. so here goes:

Simple, I have a Company model over in Rails say I do in javascript console

```
companies = new Backbone.Collection();
companies.url = '/companies';
companies.url;        // '/companies'
companies.fetch();
company = companies.at(0);
company.url
```

The last line, "company.url" doens't return what I expect, what I expect is something like '/companies/12345' so that when I update company and decide to save it, it will know where to "put" to.

So does that mean that everytime I want something saved, I have to save on the whole collection?(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually made a mistake in the step where I make an attempt to create a new companies collection. 
So instead of

var Companies = new Backbone.Collection()

I should really do something like this:

```
var Companies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Company,
  url : '/companies'
});

var Company = Backbone.Model.extend();

var companies_collection = new Companies()

companies_collection.fetch() 
companies_collection.models[0].url() // '/projects/123'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at what `company.url()` is returning. Saving the whole collection should not be necessary.

Comment: correct.. he should be looking at company.url() not company.url as the url on the model is a function not a property.

Comment: Oh yes, I told myself to put that down but forgot: company.url() returns '/companies' :(

Comment: If you're getting '/companies' when you look at url() for a model then you have no 'id' property in your data that you're using to populate Companies..

Answer (score 0):

I was trying your problem, and found that the models are not getting an id to it. So the url method on the models is not working. So i think you need to put your collections like below (what i tried)

```
        cltn = Backbone.Collection.extend({             
            model:modelName,
            parse:function(res){
                var i = 0;
                var itms = _.map(res.items, function(o){                        
                    o.id = ++i;
                    return o
                })                  
                return itms;
            }
        });
        cltnInst = new cltn();
        cltnInst.url="/combodata.json?";
        cltnInst.fetch();
```

Then in your firebug type the below codes.

```
cltnInst.url; // this is a string props. output will be "/combodata.json?"
cltnInst.at(0).url() // this is a method props output will be "/combodata.json?/1"
```

combodata.json will be of this format

```
{
"identifier": "title",
"items": [
    {
        "title": "A",
        "tag": "htmlcss",
        "date": "today"
    }, ...
]}
```

Please correct me if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Hey Rajkamal, sorry to have taken so long to reply, I think I found the problem actually.